# Failed to translate aspx files into analysis model.

Tags: visual-studio, fortify

I am seeing an issue while scanning the Visual Studio code through fortify. 
" **Failed to translate the following 21 aspx files into analysis model. Please see the log file for any errors from the aspx precompiler and the user manual for hints on fixing those.** " 
All the aspx files are getting skipped. I see no precompilation errors while running.
VS version is 2010.
Please suggest what could be the issue.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you have to give precompiled out in scan for that follow the below steps:

go to fortify.properties and uncomment this and set to false  com.fortify.VS.SkipASPPrecompilation=false (by default it is true)

in compilation element in web.config file set the debug="true"

and then create a virtual directory of the web application and add it is as website to the solution. build the website once it successful then try the fortify scan again , it should work